# SQL to prioritize company names

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table called

***filter***

```
page    companyA      companyB   companyC     filterA   filterB
page1   Google        Microsoft  Apple        hardware  web
page2   Oracle        Microsoft  Lenovo       database  web
```

***companies***

```
company      hardware     web        database
Google       YES          YES        YES
Sony         YES          YES        NO           
Oracle       NO           YES        YES
Apple        YES          YES        NO
Lenovo       YES          NO         YES
Microsoft    YES          YES        YES
```

I need to show a list of companies from table **companies** based on filtering criteria from **filter**.

For the first row from filter, for page1, I have the following variables:

```
filterA = hardware
filterB = web
```

Values of filterA and filterB are nothing but columns in companies. To build the page, I need to check if they are marked as YES.

So, for page 1, query would be:

```
select * from companies where hardware = 'YES' and web = 'YES';
```

This will output -

```
Google
Sony
Apple
Microsoft
```

But I also need to take the following columns into account - **companyA, companyB and companyC** from **filter** table.

So, for page1, the result should be:

```
Google
Microsoft
Apple
Sony
```

Any ideas on how I can tweak my select query to show ordered list based on companyA, companyB and companyC?

Comment: your `filter` table is not normalized. Can you change the table design?

Comment: you should normalize your tables

Comment: @juergend - the table is already created by someone else. I need to make use of it.

Comment: Most of our app code is written based on these tables. So cannot change much at this point.

Comment: @scaisEdge - can you tell me how I can normalize the tables?

Comment: @dang  ..  but if the tables are created by someone else and "Most of our app code is written based on these tables."  .. you think is really useful ??

Comment: @scaisEdge - yes so I can present it to the team and get this changed in the next release.

Comment: @dang  .  i have posted a brief answer

Answer (score 0):

Hi probably as you can see from comment your table are not normalized. In this case you could you a several selects with filter and UNION ALL command.

So your query will be like:

```
SELECT  
    [C].*
FROM companies AS [C] 
    INNER JOIN filter AS [F] ON [F].companyA = [C].company
WHERE hardware = 'YES' and web = 'YES'
UNION ALL
SELECT
    [C].*
FROM companies AS [C] 
    INNER JOIN filter AS [F] ON [F].companyB = [C].company
WHERE hardware = 'YES' and web = 'YES'
UNION ALL
SELECT  
    [C].*
FROM companies AS [C] 
    INNER JOIN filter AS [F] ON [F].companyC = [C].company
WHERE hardware = 'YES' and web = 'YES'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should normalize your tables

instead  of filter  and company table with fixed  column you should normalize as :

```
   table company  
    id,
    company_name

  table filter_tag
    id,
    tag

 table company_filter_status
  id_company
  id_filter_tag_id
  status /*  YES or NOT */

  table filter_relation 
    page,
    company_id,
    filter_tag_id
```

Comment: thanks for this. How about companyA, companyB and companyC priority filters?